# Using ROW_NUMBER() to find the second highest in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, row-number

Have this query (see below): 
I want to be able to use the ROW_NUMBER() function to return the record with the 2nd highest salary. I know how to use the function but I can't figure out where to put it since I have a subquery.

The query returns:

```
Yuriana Hagasawa    NULL    China   Project Manager 56000.00
Venessa Katarina    Cameron Denmark     Tech Lead   185000.00
Sahi    King    NULL    Denmark     Design Engineer 156000.00
Chen    Chen    NULL    Andorra     Project Manager 76000.00
```

so, using the row number function I want to only return the record with sahi king. Thanks.

```
SELECT C.[First Name],
C.[Last Name],
C.[Middle Name],
C.[Country Name],
C.[Designation Name],
Salary.Emp_Salary AS 'Current Salary'
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Emp_First_Name AS "First Name",
        Emp_Last_Name AS "Last Name",
        Emp_Middle_Name AS "Middle Name",
        Country_Name AS "Country Name",
        Desig_Name as "Designation Name",
        MAX(Emp_Salary_Change_Year) AS "Change Year"

        FROM Employee_Details AS e

    INNER JOIN Country AS co ON e.Emp_Country_Id = co.Country_Id
    INNER JOIN State AS s ON e.Emp_State_Id = s.State_Id
    INNER JOIN Designation AS d ON e.Desig_Id = d.Desig_Id
    INNER JOIN Salary AS sa ON e.Emp_Id = sa.Emp_Id

    GROUP BY Emp_First_Name, Emp_Last_Name,
    Emp_Middle_Name, Country_Name, Desig_Name) AS C
    INNER JOIN Salary ON C.[Change Year] = Salary.Emp_Salary_Change_Year;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the `ROW_NUMBER` with `ORDER BY Salary.Emp_Salary DESC` as below for this and if you need only the second highest then add a `where` condition `WHERE RowNo = 2` below.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT C.[First Name],
    C.[Last Name],
    C.[Middle Name],
    C.[Country Name],
    C.[Designation Name],
    Salary.Emp_Salary AS 'Current Salary',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary.Emp_Salary DESC) As RowNo
        FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Emp_First_Name AS "First Name",
            Emp_Last_Name AS "Last Name",
            Emp_Middle_Name AS "Middle Name",
            Country_Name AS "Country Name",
            Desig_Name as "Designation Name",
            MAX(Emp_Salary_Change_Year) AS "Change Year"

            FROM Employee_Details AS e

        INNER JOIN Country AS co ON e.Emp_Country_Id = co.Country_Id
        INNER JOIN State AS s ON e.Emp_State_Id = s.State_Id
        INNER JOIN Designation AS d ON e.Desig_Id = d.Desig_Id
        INNER JOIN Salary AS sa ON e.Emp_Id = sa.Emp_Id

        GROUP BY Emp_First_Name, Emp_Last_Name,
        Emp_Middle_Name, Country_Name, Desig_Name) AS C
        INNER JOIN Salary ON C.[Change Year] = Salary.Emp_Salary_Change_Year) t
WHERE RowNo = 2;
```

Comment: where does RowNo = 2 go? I tried placing it at the end and got a syntax error